# h:outputScript with target="head" not working with Primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I have a JSF application with some scripts inserted using target="head" attribute, but after including Primefaces 3.5 to the classpath, these scripts stop rendering.

Here is the page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <h:head> 
 </h:head>
   <h:body>
       <h:outputScript  target="head">
          function a(){};
        </h:outputScript>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

Removing the target attribute renders the script ok, but in the body, not in the head...

Any clues?
Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Note, I tried Primefaces 3.0 and newer and the problem persists, but PrimeFaces 2.2.1 works properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since PrimeFaces 3.0, there is a new [`HeadRenderer`](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/HeadRenderer.java) which allows customizable resource ordering. See also [this blog](https://www.primefaces.org/resource-rendering/). This has overriden the standard JSF head renderer. This is at its own okay, but apparently it failed to properly recognize inline scripts with target of head. This is clearly a bug in PrimeFaces head renderer. Your best bet is to [report](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) this issue to PF guys.

In the meanwhile, if you aren't making use of that new PrimeFaces feature at all, then just put [Mojarra's own `HeadRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.19/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HeadRenderer.java#HeadRenderer) back as default head renderer by adding the following entry to `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Note: in case you're using MyFaces instead of Mojarra, obviously reference MyFaces own one instead.